# SHELL Set the separator on a csv file

Tags: shell, sorting, csv

I need to set a separator "," on a csv file and on the entire file so it can be human readable when opened with a excel.

I have:

```
    Message,Uncounted File
    Unknown File Extension,/dir/file1
    Unknown File Extension,/dir/file2
    Unknown File Extension,/dir/file3
```

and I need

```
    Message                 Uncounted File
    Unknown File Extension  /dir/file1
    Unknown File Extension  /dir/file2
    Unknown File Extension  /dir/file3
```

Where Message uncounted file are two columns. The csv file contains reality more columns, this is an extract.
I tried

```
  S=`echo -e ","`
  sort -t"$S" myfile
```

and every sort -t possible...

Anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sed. This should give you an idea (its untested though)

```
sed -i -e 's/,/","/g' input # substitutes , with "," in file input inplace
sed -i -e 's/^|$/"/g' input # adds " to the starting and ending of each line inplace in input
```

Comment: Both of those commands don't change the input file... in any way. I don't unterstand.                                                                         `sed -i -e 's/^|$/"/g' C_CPP_outfile.csv` The file doesn't seem to have changed, at all

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't unterstand. Should I run both command on my input file ? Can you be more explicit on your comments please ?

Comment: probably your version of sed does not support -i (inplace replacement) try

Comment: probably your version of sed does not support -i (inplace replacement) try `sed -e 's/,/","/g' C_CPP_outfile.csv > input` then run the next one